# BibLaTeX (chicago) - Single-spacing bibliography items

Tags: biblatex, xetex, line-spacing

I'm using biblatex-chicago to format my dissertation, and everything works very well, except for one particular issue. My bibliography items are each double-spaced, rather than single-spaced, which is the format I need. I am using XeLaTeX, if that helps, and the biblatex-chicago authordate format.

Here is a sample of the output I receive now:
[image: Imgur]

I'd really like to get rid of that extra space between lines and have the spacing look exactly like this example:

[image: Imgur]

Is there something I need to add in my preamble to achieve this? I looked through the BibLaTeX and BibLaTeX-chicago manuals and couldn't really find anything helpful, aside from perhaps `\bibitemsep.`

Thank you very much in advance, and do let me know if you require any more information.

EDIT: Here's the .cls file I'm using, per the requirements of my school: [ufthesis.cls](http://pastebin.com/T9kT6bHS) -- and also a custom .sty they require us to use, [ufenumerate.sty](http://pastebin.com/WAqMsYXV)

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,dvipdfmx,final,CPage]{ufthesis}
\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[letterpaper,hmargin=1in,vmargin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{hanging}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{ufenumerate}
 \usepackage[format=hang,justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=0,labelsep=period]{caption}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage[autostyle=true,english=american]{csquotes}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\usepackage{hypernat}
\usepackage[dvipdfmx,hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,anchorcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,filecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,bookmarksnumbered=true,pdfview=FitB} 

\renewcommand{\topfraction}{0.85}
\renewcommand{\textfraction}{0.1}
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.75}
\begin{document}
As\footcite[See][]{knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b} was discovered \textcite[210]{cicero} and \textcite[210]{wilde} \parencite[210]{cicero} and \cite[210]{wilde}.

\textcite{wilde,cicero} vs \parencite{wilde,cicero}.\footcite{wilde}

\textcite{baez/article,wilde,cicero} vs \parencite{baez/article,wilde,cicero}.
\printbibliography[title=REFERENCES]
\end{document}
```

I did try the {\singlespacing\printbibliography} command, but it did not change anything. Hopefully this extra information should help.

EDIT: even slimming down the MWE per your suggestions, the issue still occurs. I'm required to use many of these options for my .cls, so it's not really feasible to remove any of them. I've tried to cut out the worst of the cruft, because there certainly is some there.

Comment: Which document class are you using? Which settings do you use to have double-spacing in the text? Can you provide please a minimal, complete document illustrating the problem?

Comment: I can't get a document to even compile using `biblatex-chicago` which seems weird. (I used to use it as standard.)

Comment: You may try: `{\singlespacing\printbibliography}`. (And `\usepackage{setspace}` in the preamble.)

Comment: Please post a full [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/). It looks like you are using some kind of double-spacing in your document, we will need to know how you got that going in order to switch it off for the bibliography. Not having seen any code, my best guess is something along the lines of  nicolai.rostov's suggestion. `bibitemsep` controls spacing between items, not between lines in the bibliography; but I think you might also have to adjust that length in order to get what you want.

Comment: Please add a _minimal_ example (http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225/9077). Most of the lines in your example have nothing to do with how the bibliography looks. By trying to eliminate unnecessary code, you might end up discovering what the cause of the unwanted behavior is.

Comment: You can probably add: `\setboolean{SetDSpace}{false}` right before `\printbibliography` and get single spacing back.  The problem is your class relies on idiosyncratic (if not questionable) methods for setting single and double spacing...  You might need to do a `\setboolean{SetDSpace}{true}` depending on what comes after the bibliography.  (Probably nothing, but FYI.)

Comment: Ugh, I wish I had known it was that simple. The \setboolean commands worked, both before and after the bibliography. I am actually required to have a biographical sketch after the bibliography, so unsetting SetDSpace worked perfectly to restore double-spacing.

Thank you all for all your help; my apologies for the initially unclear explanation -- and especially for the very hacky .cls with which my school provided me.

Comment: Some of the packages you load in the preamble are automatically loaded by other packages, so you do not have to include them there manually - which makes your preamble less bulky. (These packages include some of the ones you have already deleted from the MWE, as well as `url`; `setpsace` is loadad by your document class). `hypernat` is only needed if you use `natbib` and `hyperref`, since you use `biblatex` you won't need it. A good rule for packages is: If you delete it from the preamble and the document still looks the same afterwards, you can *probably* get rid of it.

Comment: Thanks again, moewe, for your help! The .cls originally used natbib, but I ended up having to switch to BibLaTeX, so there was bound to be some cruft that needed to be removed. All is well after removing some of those extraneous packages, so I'm quite happy with things!

Answer (score 2):

Per jon's comment above,
`\setboolean{SetDSpace}{false}` worked, with my custom .cls, to change double- to single-spacing, and `\setboolean{SetDSpace}{true}` will restore double-spacing.

Thank you all for your help!